# How to connect two docker containers through localhost?

Tags: docker, sails.js, boot2docker

I have two services running in separate containers, one is grunt(application) and runs off port 9000 and the other is sails.js (server) which runs off port 1337. What I want to try to do is have the client app connect with the server through localhost:1337. Is this feasible? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### HOST

You won't be able to connect to the other container with `localhost` (as `localhost` is the current container) but you can connect via the container host (the host that is running your container). In your case you need boot2docker VM IP (`echo $(boot2docker ip)`). For this to work, you need to expose your port at the host level (which you are doing with `-p 1337:1337`).

#### LINK

Another solution that is most common and that I prefer when possible, is to link the containers.

You need to add the --name flag to the server `docker run` command:
`--name sails_server`

You need to add the --link flag to the application `docker run` command:
`--link sails_server:sails_server`

And inside your application, you will be able to access the server at `sail_server:1337`
You could also use environment variables to get the server IP. See documentation: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

#### BONUS: DOCKER-COMPOSE

Your run commands may start to be a bit long... in this case I like to use [docker-compose](http://www.fig.sh/yml.html) that allows me to define my containers and their relationships (volumes, names, link, commands...) in one file.

Comment: Ah kk, is the sails_server an environment variable or do I just access it directly in my .js file?

Comment: @reconman when you link containers, Docker update the `/etc/hosts` file so you can use `sails_server` directly.

Comment: I'm not satisfied. Is there really no way to achieve the original goal?

Answer (score -2):

Yes if you use docker parameter -p 1337:1337 in your docker run command, it will expose the port 1337 from inside the container to your localhost:1337

Comment: I have tried that, I can access 1337 from the host IP but the application isn't able to connect to localhost:1337. Thanks.

Comment: "localhost" inside a container is the container itself. You need to use the IP of the host instead. Or you could just use docker links.

Comment: are you running docker inside a VM? this is the case if you are using Mac OSX or windows then it runs inside a VM called boot2docker