# Why two containers on the same docker machine can't communicate through localhost?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-toolbox

Getting started with Docker I do not understand why two containers on the same docker machine can't communicate through **localhost**.

I read about this SO post already : [how-to-connect-two-docker-containers-through-localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143903/how-to-connect-two-docker-containers-through-localhost) but could not get a clear answer.

My use case, I am on Windows Home using Docker Toolbox (virtualbox) having the current docker machine :

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v19.03.5
```

I am launching 3 services, one **react** application, one **spring boot** application, and one **postgreSQL** database.

In my understanding each one will be hosted on **192.168.99.100** on the port I specified (respectively 3000, 8080, 5432). So each one in their context should have **localhost** refering to **192.168.99.100**.

I know it is not working like that because of **CORS** issues that I only get when launching the app environment with docker.

Why is that ? Can someone explain ?

Comment: Each _container_ has its own network namespace and its own notion of `localhost`.  (Which is synonymous with the magic IP address 127.0.0.1.)  `localhost` usually means "this container" and not "this Docker VM" or "this physical host".  Also note that the React application runs in the browser, not in Docker space, so `localhost` there refers to the machine the browser is running on.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the link it's indead a duplicate !